# User PowerShell to Delete Contents of Folder, but Ignore Files Currently in Use

Tags: powershell, delete-file

Long story short, I have a customer who is trying to figure out why logs are filling up their server.  That's not really something I need to worry about, other than I need to continually go through and clear out logs from a ton of servers so my application can run.  I'm trying to figure out a script that will clear out the log folder.  Ideally, this should work:

`Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Include *.* -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}`

but some of the files are still in  use, so I'm getting this:

```
Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file 
'filename' because it is being used by another process."
At line:1 char:87
+ ... $filePath -Include *.* -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}
+                                                           
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException
```

Is there something I can add to this to ignore files that are still in use?

Comment: Does the error break the pipeline? If the answer is no, then you might want to just suppress the error message and keep doing exactly what you have right now

Comment: It appears to.  I still have the same 26,000+ files in the folder that I had before.  Maybe I'm missing something else... If I manually delete them, I'm told I need admin permission to delete them. I click to approve that, then am prompted that the files are too large and I need to permanently delete them.  I click to approve that and am then asked to try again or ignore the files that are still in use. I click to ignore those files, and it keeps just those, deleting everything else.  My script does not appear to be deleting anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not interested in keeping log of what files where deleted and which files were in use you can simply pipe `Get-ChildItem` to `Remove-Item` and use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` (`-EA 0` for short) to suppress the error messages.

Note the use of `-File` is easier and more efficient than `-Include *.*`.
You can also add `-Force` for [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.2):

> Forces the cmdlet to remove items that cannot otherwise be changed, such as hidden or read-only files or read-only aliases or variables.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $filepath -File -Recurse -EA 0 | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -EA 0
```

Comment: My hope is to ignore the files that are in use and keep them, while deleting everything else.

Comment: @ChristopherCass yeah, my point is, if the file is in use it will be ignored. This command should delete those files that 1. you have permission to delete and 2. they're not in use. If the file is __read-only__ you would need to add the `-Force` switch

Comment: Ah.  Trying it now, thank you!  So far running with no errors.   Hoping I can just add this as a scheduled task so I don't have to do this again.

Comment: @ChristopherCass you're not seeing any errors because `-EA 0` is suppressing all of them

Comment: This did not appear to work.  This particular server started with 1600 files in the folder and saw no change after running the script.  Manually deleting the files got rid of all but 103 files that were still in use and didn't delete.

Comment: Did you try using the `-Force` switch as I noted in the answer?

Comment: There it goes.  I missed that one. Thanks for the help!